# Invoke JS function in IFrame window

Tags: javascript, function, iframe

I have a JS function which I sometimes want to invoke in the context of the main window, and sometimes in the client window. Something like the following:

```
var f = function() { alert(window.location); };

f(); // should show the location of the parent frame

// DOESN'T WORK, but is intended to show the location of the first IFrame
f.call(window.frames[0]);
```

Googling this mostly shows me how to invoke a function which is *defined* in the child frame. I, however, want to take a function which is defined in the parent and *execute* it in the child frame. And, to eliminate the obvious, adding a `window` parameter to the function is not a viable option.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute a function defined in a parent window but in the context of your window, you can use [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
top.someFunction.apply(window);
```

The two windows must be in the same domain for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `window` with `top` if you're calling a function that exists in the global scope of the parent page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like the following:

```
// reference to window in iframe with id or name 'myIframe'
var win = window.frames['myIframe'];

// invoke function in win
win.getEvents();
```